# Can angles between 2 vectors be negative?

Tags: vectors, angle

Can angle between two be negative? Everywhere I read, it was written that angle is less then 180⁰ and greater than 0⁰. However, we can also rotate the other vector clockwise so we can have negative angle. So why is that not allowed?

Comment: That’s not an angle between two vectors. It’s the angle starting at one and turning toward the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A ***directed angle*** naturally can be negative:

   - as **complex number argument**s, the directed angles $356^\circ, -4^\circ$ and$-364^\circ$ are equivalent to one another;
   - however, $364^\circ$ is a greater **angle of rotation** than $4^\circ.$
2. On the other hand, an ***undirected angle*** is conventionally specified on some interval:

   - an **angle in a triangle** lies strictly between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ;$ for example, the Sine Rule is formulated such that $30^\circ$ and $-30^\circ$ are not arbitrarily interchangeable;
   - the **angle $\alpha$ between two vectors** is defined on $[0^\circ,180^\circ];$ as such, it is nonstandard to refer to such an $89^\circ$ angle as $-89^\circ$ or $271^\circ$ or $-271^\circ$ or $449^\circ;$
   - the **angle $\beta$ between two lines** is defined on $[0^\circ,90^\circ].$

P.S. Each 'nonstandard' angle $x$ by can be converted to $\alpha,$ and likewise for $\beta:$ $$\alpha=\arccos(\cos(x))\\\beta=\left|\arctan(\tan(x))\right|.$$ For example, $$89^\circ=\arccos(\cos(-271^\circ))\\60^\circ=\left|\arctan(\tan(120^\circ))\right|.$$

Answer (score 5):

In principle, there's nothing wrong with letting the angle be negative.

However, limiting the angle between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$ is natural, because it is the smallest of the two angles formed by a pair of non-parallel vectors in the plane they span, and it lends itself to the simple calculation of

$$\text{the angle between $x,y$} = \arccos \left( \frac{x \cdot y}{|x|\cdot |y|} \right)$$

The arccosine function has a range between $0$ and $\pi$ radians, meaning it naturally outputs the aforementioned smaller angle.

(In short, then, there is no issue, but this convention is both geometrically intuitive and computationally simple.)

Comment: worth mentioning that $\cos$ is an even function. So, $\cos(-\alpha) = cos(\alpha)$

Comment: I think it depends if you look at angle as a function of an ordered pair of vectors, i.e. $\text{angle}(v_0,v_1)$, in which case it would make sense to expect an outcome in $[0,360)$ or $[-180,180)$, or if you look at angle as function of an undordered pair, like $\text{angle}(\{v_0,v_1\})$, in which case it make sense to limit to $[0,180]$.